# C++ : Vector assignment in constructor error

Tags: c++, vector, constructor

in my program i Have following class:

```
#ifndef CORNERS_H
#define CORNERS_H

#include <vector>

class Corners{
public:
    Corners();
    Corners( std::vector<unsigned short int>,std::vector<unsigned short int> );
    Corners( std::vector<unsigned short int>,std::vector<unsigned short int>,
            std::vector<unsigned short int>, std::vector<unsigned short int> );

    void set2Corners( std::vector<unsigned short int>,std::vector<unsigned short int> );
    void set4Corners( std::vector<unsigned short int>,std::vector<unsigned short int>,
            std::vector<unsigned short int>, std::vector<unsigned short int> );

    std::vector<unsigned short int> getA();
    std::vector<unsigned short int> getB();
    std::vector<unsigned short int> getC();
    std::vector<unsigned short int> getD();


private:
    std::vector<unsigned short int> colA;
    std::vector<unsigned short int> colB;
    std::vector<unsigned short int> colC;
    std::vector<unsigned short int> colD;
};

#endif // CORNERS_H
```

Default constructor for this class looks like this:

```
Corners::Corners(){

    colA[RED] = 5;
    colA[GREEN] = 5;
    colA[BLUE] = 5;

    colB[RED] = 31;
    colB[GREEN] = 63;
    colB[BLUE] = 31;

    colC=colA;
    colD=colB;

}
```

RED GREEN BLUE are enums defined in another file.
For my whole program, I get no errors when building.
When i want to make instance of the class in my main, for example:

```
Corners start;
```

When I run the program, it freezes and quits with error "Segmentation fault".I have no idea why it is so, does anyone has any idea?

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: How about `using CustomVector = std::vector<unsigned short int>;` ;)

Comment: It appears he needs `using colorTuple = std::array<unsigned short int>;`, and then `std::array<colorTuple> cols;`

Comment: If you only and always have 3 elements, consider `std::array`; however a `class Colour` with `red`, `green` and `blue` members may be easier to read.

Comment: Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem, then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the vectors are length 0, so you cannot assign to locations. You first have to initialize their length.

```
Corners::Corners()
   : colA(3)
   , colB(3)
   , colC(3)
   , colD(3)
{
    colA[RED] = 5;
    colA[GREEN] = 5;
    colA[BLUE] = 5;

    colB[RED] = 31;
    colB[GREEN] = 63;
    colB[BLUE] = 31;

    colC=colA;
    colD=colB;
}
```

Or even like Mooing Duck suggested.

```
Corners::Corners()
   : colA{5, 5, 5}
   , colB{31, 63, 31}
   , colC(colA)
   , colD(colB)
{}
```

.. which could be inlined, like he shows.

but maybe you should switch to `std::array<unsigned short int, 3>`.
And use `using CustomArray=std::array<unsigned short int, 3>;` so you don't have to write that long definition every time.

edit: and as user4581301 suggests, even better is:

```
struct Color {
    unsigned short int Red;
    unsigned short int Green;
    unsigned short int Blue;
};
```

Comment: Your member initialization list is needlessly complex, you are invoking the `vector` copy constructor when you should be using the initialization constructor. You can simplify the list to just this: `: colA(3), colB(3)` (`colC` and `colD` are assigned in the body and so don't need explicit construction, and there is no `colE` declared).

Comment: `Corners::Corners() : colA{5, 5, 5}, colB{31,63,31}, colC(colA), colD(colD) {}`

Comment: Just note that `colA{5, 5, 5}, colB{31,63,31}` only works in C++11 and later

Comment: Yes you're right, but C++ is already 6 years old... Most modern compilers support it.

Comment: Thanks, it fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

Your vectors have no capacity. Vectors don't automatically resize when using the subscript operator. You can call the resize() method on colA and colB, and pass in one greater than the max of {RED,GREEN,BLUE} before setting the values. For example, if BLUE is the largest in your enum:

```
Corners::Corners() {
    colA.resize(BLUE + 1);
    colB.resize(BLUE + 1);

    colA[RED] = 5;
    colA[GREEN] = 5;
    colA[BLUE] = 5;

    colB[RED] = 31;
    colB[GREEN] = 63;
    colB[BLUE] = 31;

    colC=colA;
    colD=colB;
}
```